# understanding nodejs code: What is app.get function? angularBootModule?

Tags: javascript

Help me in understanding the code. This will be very helpful for Angular JS beginners.

```
------------
LoginPage.js
------------
exports.signupform = function(req, res) {
    res.render('login', {
        title: 'Signin',
        angularBootModule: 'login',
        message: req.flash('error')
    });
};

exports.logout = function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
};

    enter code here

--------
main.js
--------
 var loginController = require('/page/LoginPage.js');
    app.get('/signup', loginController.signupform);
    app.get('/logout', loginController.logout);
```

I am new to angular js. Here I understand that in the main.js file, LoginPage.js is loaded. Then we are invoking signupForm function.

---

### Questions

What is this app.get function? Why this 'signup' argument?

We have defined two arguments req,res newly for the function signupform. How come render function come into picture? Does all Javascript objects have this render method by default?

What is the use of assigining angularBootModule: 'login'. What will it do?

Comment: This doesn't look like AngularJS at all. Maybe it is some sort of compatibility library integrating Angular with something else?

Comment: That looks more like node.js to me. Is there a node.js server tied to the project? I agree with package, that doesn't look like any angular I've ever seen.

Comment: Yes its node.js Can you please explain me the app.get function? What is angularbootmodule used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an AngularJS expert. In fact, I've never coded in AngularJS before or even looked at a single line of AngularJS code before today. However, I think my answers will be more helpful to you, a fellow beginner, because of how I arrived at them.

`app.get` makes a `GET` request to the server for a resource. `/signup` is the path to this resource on the server. I learned this by browsing through the tutorial section of the AngularJS website: [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#controller).

Probably the arguments to `signupform` are `req`, which is short for "[request](http://djce.org.uk/dumprequest)", and `res`, which is short for "response". This leads me to believe that the second argument to `app.get` is a callback, a function that will be executed when the `GET` request finishes. The fact that `res` has a method `render` makes me think that the response must be some kind of template, because in client-side apps we often "[render templates](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/templates)".

Not every javascript object has a method `render`, so this object must be something that you the programmer needs to define on the server side. Often when working with a framework like AngularJS you will need to wear a few different hats: you will probably need to implement a relatively simple server, maybe in [Ruby on Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/), [Sinatra](http://joeyates.info/2010/04/07/a-beginners-sinatra-tutorial/), or [Django](http://www.creativebloq.com/netmag/get-started-django-7132932). This server will respond to requests, passing data to your client-side app. However, each of these frameworks will itself be a learning endeavour! More hats!

As for `angularBootModule`, I'm not sure. ^o^//

It sounds to me like you are just starting with web-development. StackOverflow is a great place to get answers to your questions, but it doesn't look like just the answers will be enough for you right now. If someone had answered your question by saying:

1. it is making a GET request for '/signup'
2. the render function will cause the response to be show.
3. no

You would have your answers, but you would not be any better for them. I recommend going to the [AngularJS tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) and following it completely, looking up everything you don't understand. You might even be better off starting with a tutorial for a server-side framework like [Sinatra](http://joeyates.info/2010/04/07/a-beginners-sinatra-tutorial/), so that you will have a better understanding of HTTP and how websites work.

Thanks for posting to StackOverflow! Good luck on your journey!

Comment: If I read the situation wrong, and you aren't actually a true beginner, please don't take offence!

Comment: NodeJS for the backend is also a viable choice, nice post though!

Comment: Ha ha, can you tell I'm a rubyist? Actually, NodeJS is probably the best choice since they OP won't need to learn an entirely new language. Can you suggest a tutorial?

Comment: I've learned ExpressJS by following a course on [pluralsight](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=expressjs&highlight=). There is also a tutorial on Nettuts+ about [ExpressJS](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/build-a-complete-mvc-web-site-with-expressjs/), but I haven't tried this one yet..